# initializer_list in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, initializer

I found that initializer_list is not supported by MSVC 2012. But can it (initializer_list)
be used in VS somehow (with the help of Boost library for example). Samples if you can, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Boost::assign](http://www.boost.org/libs/assign/) is as close as you get.

More specifically, [assign::list_of](http://www.boost.org/libs/assign/#list_of) is probably similar to the behavior you're looking for.

```
// Examples from the documentation:
const list<int> primes = list_of(2)(3)(5)(7)(11);
const stack<string> names = list_of( "Mr. Foo" )( "Mr. Bar")( "Mrs. FooBar" ).to_adapter();
map<int,int> next = map_list_of(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)(5,6);
```